# Having Windows Fit in Proportion With Active Monitor on OS X

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors

I have a 15 inch MacBook with a large monitor connected to it.  The resolution on my monitor is much higher than that on my laptop.  When I move an active window from the monitor to my laptop, the active window is much larger than the actual screen size of the laptop so most of the window is cut off.

Is there anyway to config your OS X system so that windows scale to proportion when you move it over to the laptop screen?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Multimon](http://www.multimonapp.com/), it should automatically resize windows when moving them to a different monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Spectacle](http://spectacleapp.com/) to move and resize windows with ease. You can customize every shortcuts.

Usually, when I move a windows through different screens, I'm not using same proportions.